# Append to the end of an array

Tags: c, arrays, list, segmentation-fault, append

My goal is to append a List to the end of an array. When i try to execute it give me segmentation fault.

I tried to make a little debug and the istruction that give me prolem is in the for cicle:

```
array[i] = tmp[i];
```

This is my code:

```
int i;
List *tmp = array;

array = (List *)malloc((dim+1) * sizeof(List));

for (i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
    array[i] = tmp[i];
}

dim++;

array[dim-1] = (List)malloc(sizeof(struct TList));
memcpy(array[dim-1], set, sizeof(struct TList));

return array;
```

Where "dim" it's a global variable that i use to track the dimension of the array

I know that probably it's simple to do, but i really don't know how to solve this problem.

Thanks for help

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]? Now we don’t know what `array` is beforehand for example. Also casting a pointer from `malloc` to List seems weird, as well as `array` containing non-pointer content and trying to put dynamically allocated memory into it.

Comment: List *addToProcessedNode(List *array,List set)

Comment: This is the List type

Comment: This is the list type

Comment: @xing you are very right, still now I supposed List is a struct, to be a pointer changes all

Answer (score 0):

First remark :

```
int i;
List *tmp = array;

array = (List*)malloc((dim+1) * sizeof(List));

for (i = 0;i < dim;i++){

  array[i] = tmp[i];

}
```

Can be just that :

```
array = realloc(array, (dim+1) * sizeof(List));
```

---

in `array[dim-1] = (List)malloc(sizeof(struct TList));` why the type in the cast is not also the type in the *sizeof* ?

But the true question is what do you expect doing that assignment except to loose memory through a memory leak ?

That line must be removed.

---

What are the definition of *TList* and *list* and the type of *set* ?

---

The line

```
memcpy(array[dim-1], set, sizeof(struct TList));
```

is wrong and must be (*set* must be a List)

```
array[dim-1] = set;
```

because array is vector of *List*, not a vector of *List **

Comment: This tis the list type                                                                                          
                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                         
  struct TList {
    int target;
    int id;
    int peso;
    struct TList* next;
};

typedef struct TList* List;

Comment: As an aside, note that passing `array` as the first parameter to `realloc` will result in a memory leak if `realloc` fails, as the returned null pointer will be assigned to `array` but the block originally referenced by `array` will *not* be `free`d.

Comment: @MedardoCalabresi array is a vector of List, not a Vector of List *, `array[dim-1] = (List)malloc`...` is wrong because it is a memory leak and the malloc return a List * so the Cast is wrong too, and finaly that assignment is useless

Comment: @MedardoCalabresi I did not see List is a pointer, so finaly you have to replace `memcpy(array[dim-1], set, sizeof(struct TList));` by `array[dim-1] = set;`